# Destruction of .NET Objects by CLR

Tags: .net, clr

How is any .NET object without any dispose() or finalize pattern destroyed by clr?
is it cleared by  the Object Finalize Method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to get a good overview of what the Dispose pattern does.

> In some cases, you might want to provide programmers using an object with the ability to explicitly release these external resources before the garbage collector frees the object. If an external resource is scarce or expensive, better performance can be achieved if the programmer explicitly releases resources when they are no longer being used.

Comment: I Know CLR runs as a different thread. But how it has got the super privelege to call the finalize methods objects belonging to the App thread. Remember in a typical bg thread/ GUI we need to do a control.invoke!

Comment: @NSN: How? Simple: the finalizers are well written and don't throw. They don't have thread affinity like other GUI control methods. Do you think that would make sense?

Answer (score 7):

No, if the object does not declare an explicit finalizer it is never added to the freachable queue - its memory is simply reclaimed.

This is one of the reasons that you should not declare a finalizer unless you really need one. Any objects that have finalizers require two passes of the GC to be fully collected.

---

From [`Object.Finalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx):

> `Object.Finalize` does nothing by
>   default. It must be overridden by a
>   derived class only if necessary,
>   because reclamation during garbage
>   collection tends to take much longer
>   if a Finalize operation must be run.

Also I would recommend that you check out [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

Comment: Then why we need dispose method!

Comment: That's his point, you don't NEED it. If you WANT it, you can supply one, and the CLR will comply for a cost.

Comment: Also, you can manually call the GC after a much-memory consuming process finalizes, to destroy those objects. But this is not always recommended because calling the GC can be very resource consuming itself.

Comment: You usually need it when there is something else that needs to be finalized, beyond just memory. For instance, the `System.IO.File` class does implement a finalizer - it is used to close the file handle. Also, when a class has a finalizer, it usually implements `System.IDisposable`. That way you can use it inside [using statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage Collector will eventually reclaim the memory used by an object, after it can no longer be reached by any references. This is the only cleanup that will occur unless the object has a finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to imagine the garbage collector in .net as operating in a way similar to the way a bowling-alley pinsetter clears out "deadwood" (knocked-over pins):

1. Move all of the pins which should not be cleared out (i.e. the ones which are still standing) off the surface of the alley.

   Run the sweeper across the whole surface of the alley, clearing out wholesale anything that was there.

   Put the pins back.

Note that at no stage of the operation does the pinsetter detect or target any of the knocked-over pins.  It neither knows nor cares whether there is one such pin or nine of them (if no pins are standing, the pinsetter will register a strike and skip the second half of a frame).  From the standpoint of the pinsetter, those pins may as well not exist until such time as they reach the mechanism that can recycle them.